# " ...to legitimate goals..."

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Was the word **legitimate** used as a verb or adjective in the following sentence? If it was used as a verb what does **"to legitimate goals"** mean?

> Individuals who have a sincere commitment to legitimate goals are more
>   likely to conform to society's norm.

Answer (score 1):

*Legitimate* is not a verb here.  It's an adjective and modifies *goals*.  (I have never heard *legitimate* used as a verb though I'm sure someone somewhere has written a sentence using it that way.)

*To legitimate goals* is a prepositional phrase that qualifies *a sincere commitment* - *to* expresses the relation between *sincere commitment* and *legitimate goals* which is one of "targeting".  (*For* would work as well.)

*To* does not always signify an infinitive (and an infinitive can exist with out *to*).

Comment: oh thank you.I was to ask about for, but you've already answered it .

Comment: "I have never heard legitimate used as a verb" me neither, but the dictionaries say that it might be. [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/legitimate_2) says it's a BrE vs. AmE thing: "le‧git‧i‧mate [transitive] the usual American form of legitimize" :-)